# jquery .next() missing injected form element

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am somewhat stumped by the behaviour of the .next('selector') method when applied to the html:

```
<form>
   <label for="relayhosts" class="fixedwidth">Relay Host(s)</label>  
   <input style="display: none;" name="relayhosts" value="" type="text">   
   <input class="ip_octet" id="octet_1" type="text">
   <label class="ip_octet_label">.</label>
   <input class="ip_octet" id="octet_2" type="text">
   <label class="ip_octet_label">.</label>
   <input class="ip_octet" id="_octet_3" type="text">
   <label class="ip_octet_label">.</label>
   <input class="ip_octet" id="octet_4" type="text">
</form>
```

Using `$('#octet_1').next('input');` returns no result yet `$('#octet_1').next().next();` returns the next input as expected.

I have also tried `$('#octet_1').next('input.ip_octet');` and `$('#octet_1').next('.ip_octet');` both of which return nothing.

The input and label elements were dynamically generated but as the **next.().next()** method sees them it would not seem to be an issue with the objects existing in the DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) returns the next element **only** if it matches the selector.

[`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) on the other hand, searches all the next elements and returns those that matches the selector.

So, you probably want:

```
nextAll('input:first');
```

(see the [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/))

... or

```
nextAll('input').first();
```

... depending on personal preference.

Comment: You star! I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery Next method](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

```
$('#octet_1').nextAll('input')
```